# Create a Vim command to add a php debug statement

Tags: vim, php

I'm trying to create a vim command to easily insert a debug statement on the variable name under the cursor. I would at least like to handle some common cases so it doesn't have to be perfect but the following should all work:

```
$test_var = array($test->get_test_var()) || $test->get_test_var() || $test_var;
```

Having the cursor over any of these variable names and running the command should insert a line above the call with the value of the expression inside. E.g. place the cursor over anything in '$test->get_test_var()' and then the following is inserted above on a new line:

```
print_r($test->get_test_var());
```

Placing the cursor over 'array(**$test->get_test_var()**)' should insert the same thing and not include the array. Placing it over array should do this:

```
print_r(array($test->get_test_var()));
```

And finally, placing it over '$test_var;' should insert the following (not including the semicolon):

```
print_r($test_var);
```

Obviously I'm working on this myself, but some of you could have insight on how to do this easily that I will miss as a relatively new user of vim.

Comment: It's pretty easy to do if you're willing to visually select the text you want to insert (see ":help 04.4" and ":help visual-mode") or the text is something Vim recognizes as a text object (see ":help 04.8" and ":help text-objects"), but Vim doesn't understand PHP expressions, so there is no easy way that I know of (short of writing a PHP parser in Vim script) to select a PHP variable or expression after putting the cursor in it as you would like.

Answer (score 0):

If you put something like this in your vimrc, you'll autoreplace %DATE% with the format:

```
    iab %DATE% <c-r>=strftime("%a %d %b %Y")
```

For simpler stuff, put in:

```
    iab br best regards,<CR><CR>Your Name
```

This will replace "br" with best regards etc.

So you could try something like:

```
    iab debugr ...
```

Not sure if you need to press enter in order to replace, but give it a try.

Comment: I already came up with a command like that to insert the date (map <silent> <F9> :r ! date "+\%m-\%d-\%Y"<CR>
map <silent> <s-F9> :r ! date "+\%m-\%d-\%Y \%H:\%M:\%S"<CR>)
but I'm thinking you mistakenly posted that here.